# How to load or manage large OpenStreetMap file in Blender for simulation

Tags: python, animation, add-on

I am working on a simulation in Blender for syrian refugee migration. That requires a relatively large OpenStreetMap file, covering most of the inhabited parts of Syria. I have a fair bit of RAM on my computer (24GB), but was trying to think about simulation performance with such a large file. I was wondering what is the best way to handle such a large file in Blender? I can try to limit the detail keep the map relatively zoomed out--though I would like the ability to zoom in to the detail if I want to.

So this is the idea. Can I manage this in Blender?

Comment: In terms on performance think this way: The resolution of the textures should not be any larger than the number of pixels they will use on the screen on the final product. It makes no sense to have textures that are thuosands of pixels when they will only use a few pixels on the screen. Use a lower res texture for scenes that will display larger areas of the map.  If you need highly detailed maps for certain segments that focus on a small area, do not use a single very large image, but use tiled segments, so that blender has to load only the visible ones at rendering time.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen it yet there is an addon to [import OSM data](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo)

When it comes to working with and rendering large scenes there are some things you can do to make it easier.

Use particles or [linked duplicates](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/duplication/introduction.html#linked-duplicates). When objects use the same mesh data, only one copy of vertex data needs to be held in RAM, when the polygons are drawn they get "transformed" into position based on the location of the duplicate item being drawn. If you haven't seen the [post about the island flyover video](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?356978-Cycles-Island-revisited-vol-2), the island has 450,000 tree and rock particles which reports as over 1 trillion vertices at render and was done in 12GB of RAM.

When creating the scene, set the display of each object as bounding box, this will keep the number of vertices used to draw in the viewport low while rendering will use the detailed mesh.

[image: object display settings]

Then when you want to see what a part of the scene will look like, use render border <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to define a small square in the viewport before you switch to rendered view to see the full detail in that area.

Use tricks used in 3D games. Keep the objects low poly and use materials and normal maps to make them appear more detailed. You can use some higher poly meshes in the area you want to zoom into and keep the remaining 90% of houses with low poly counts.